# Why do I need to update a bound combobox manually?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework-6

**My Setup**

I have following (pseudo) EF classes:

```
class Department {
    int ID,
    string Name
}

class DepartmentCustomer {
    int ID,
    int CustomerID,
    Customer Customer,
    string Information,
    int DepartmentID,
    Department Department
}

Class Customer {
    int ID,
    string Name,
    int? CityID,
    City City
}

Class City{
    int ID,
    string Name,
    string PostalCode
}
```

I have a form with a BindingSource for `List(of DepartmentCustomer)` and the following fields :

- `DepartmentCustomer.Information` as a (read-write) textbox
- `DepartmentCustomer.Customer.Name` as a (readonly) textbox
- `DepartmentCustomer.Customer.City` as a (read-write) combobox.

[image: CustomerForm]

The combobox for the city name has following properties:

```
ComboBoxCity.DataSource = ListOfCities  ' = List(Of City)
ComboBoxCity.ValueMember = "Id"
ComboBoxCity.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem", DepartmentCustomerBindingSource, "Customer.City", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

**My Problem**

When `DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.CurrentItemChanged` occurs, the Combobox is not synchronized; it sometimes updates to the correct value, but when navigating further through the BindingSource it keeps the previous item selected

So, I have to do the following to update the combobox manually

```
Private Sub DepartmentCustomerBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.CurrentItemChanged
    If DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.Current.Contact.City Is Nothing then
        ComboBoxCity.SelectedIndex = -1
    Else
        ComboBoxCity.SelectedItem = DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.Current.Contact.City
    End if
End Sub
```

(for the sake of simplicity I have ommitted casting in my code above. Also these example classes might not make sense IRL)

**EDIT**

*Even the code above does not do what I want.
For example: I have two instances of DepartmentCustomer, one with a Contact.City, the second without a Contact.City . When the form opens at the first instance, it shows the city; when I navigate to the second record, the combobox becomes empty, but when I go back to the first combobox, it stays empty; even more surprising, the first record has been updated to Contact.City = Nothing :'(*

**EDIT 2: My own not-preferred solution**

I have removed the databinding from the combobox (`ComboBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem", DepartmentCustomerBindingSource, "Customer.City", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))`) and added the following sub

```
Private Sub ComboBoxCity_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxCity.SelectedValueChanged
    DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.Current.Contact.City = ComboBoxCity.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

This works, but since I have quite a lot of these comboboxes in my form, I think there has to be an "automatic" way of synchronizing a two-way bound combobox...

**Edit 3: I throw in the towel**

Even my above "solution" is not working as expected; the Contact.City of the instances are not updated correctly when using the above code...

**My Question**

Why do I have to to this manually; Am I missing something? I would think that by setting the DataBinding, it would update the SelectedItem whenever the bound BindingSource is being navigated;

Comment: Most of time when a control doesn't update it's an issue related to the interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged and IBinding​List not (correctly) implemented.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard thanks!!! see my answer below (and my additional question)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue (bug?) with `ComboBox` data binding to `SelectedItem` property and null (`Nothing`) source values.

From the other side binding to `SelectedValue` has no such issue. So the solution/workaround is to bind to `SelectedItem` for updating the data soource and to `SelectedValue` for updating the control:

```
ComboBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem", DepartmentCustomerBindingSource, "Customer.City", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))    
ComboBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", DepartmentCustomerBindingSource, "Customer.City.ID", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never))
```

Comment: Really? that would seem crazy. Any references perhaps?

Comment: Reference? You have to be kidding :) Trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

> Most of time when a control doesn't update it's an issue related to the interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged and IBinding​List not (correctly) implemented. – Marco Guignard

This got me thinking: I was indeed using the following to populate the DepartmentCustomerBindingSource

```
DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.DataSource = DBContext.DepartmentCustomer.Local.ToList
```

When changing that to

```
DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.DataSource = DBContext.DepartmentCustomer.Local.ToBindingList
```

it works :-/

However, how do I get this working when setting the datasource to a specific record instead of a (Binding)List?

```
DepartmentCustomerBindingSource.DataSource = DBContext.DepartmentCustomer.Local.First
```

Comment: Add the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged to the DepartmentCustomer Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2 By the way you better have to use ForeignKey Property to do the link between the selected value of your combo box

Comment: @MarcoGuignard I am clueless on why and how I have to do that. Does everybody who wants to use a Combobox to update a EF POCO have to implement this?

Comment: On the comboBox, set the datasource to a collection Of City (a list is good enough if you don't update the list of city), set the DisplayMember to Name and the ValueMember to ID. Then set a binding between the SelectedValue of the combobox and the CityID property of your BindingSource containing your Customer.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial-and-error I found the following solution:

Taking following code in consideration:

```
ComboBoxCity.DataSource = ListOfCities  ' = List(Of City)
ComboBoxCity.ValueMember = "Id"
ComboBoxCity.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedItem", DepartmentCustomerBindingSource, "Customer.City", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

the thing that got me going was to set the `ComboBoxCity.DataSource` to a type that implements IBindingList, like following:

```
DBContext.Cities.Load
CitiesBindingSource.DataSource = DBContext.Cities.Local.ToBindingList
ComboBoxCity.DataSource = CitiesBindingSource
```

So, it was not the bound data (in this case `DepartmentCustomerBindingSource`) that had to be a BindingList, but only the Datasource had to implement IBindingSource...